# Does Robot Class functionality behaves correctly independent of the OS we use?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to upload an image in the div section with the help of following code which makes use of Robot Class.

Test Environment:

```
OS: Mac OS,
Selenium: WebDriver,
Client: Java.
```

Code:

```
StringSelection imagePath = new StringSelection("/Users/admin/Desktop/TestImages Ordering/resto-img/fansushi.jpg");

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(imagePath, null);

Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Will this code work independent of the OS we use?

Answer (score 2):

No, reason being Different OS works differently. The way we copy and paste things in MAC differs from Windows. Secondly the way MAC OS supports java also differs from windows. so we need different code for different OS.

Answer (score 0):

VK_CONTROL does not work on MACOS, we need keypress event for **COMMAND KEY** I searched online but I could not find anything for Command Button

Comment: Please refer the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418987/java-robot-keypress-command-key. Refer the answer: [`KeyEvent.VK_META`][1], with key code `157`, is Java's virtual key that maps to the the Mac command key.